# Dynamic add fields mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a form where i want to post data to save in my database. The use must be able to add fields manually if he wants to add more Competences he can click on a button mAddCompetence , when the user clicks on this button there will be 3 extra input fields. My code for this form is:

```
<fieldset>
    <!-- Competenties -->
    <legend>Competenties</legend>
    <div id="competenceListAdd" class="form-group">
        <div id="competenceFormCloneMe">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Competence,
                    new SelectList(Model.Competences, "CompetenceId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Competence)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModuleHasCompetence.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Omschrijving van competentie" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ModuleHasCompetence.Description)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModuleHasCompetence.Difficulty, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(WatervalDomain.ModuleHasCompetence.DifficultyEnum))), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ModuleHasCompetence.Difficulty)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="mAddCompetence" name="mAddCompetence" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Add competence</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#mAddCompetence').click(function () {
            $('#competenceListAdd').append('</br></br>'); +
            $('#competenceListAdd').append($('#competenceFormCloneMe').clone());
        });
    </script>
</fieldset>
```

In html it is

```
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Competenties -->
        <legend>Competenties</legend>
        <div id="competenceListAdd" class="form-group">
            <div id="competenceFormCloneMe">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Competence must be a number." data-val-required="Het veld Competence is vereist." id="Competence" name="Competence">
                        <option value="1">option1</option>
                        <option value="2">option1.</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Competence" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="required" id="ModuleHasCompetence_Description" name="ModuleHasCompetence.Description"             <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ModuleHasCompetence.Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="required" id="ModuleHasCompetence_Difficulty" name="ModuleHasCompetence.Difficulty">
                        <option>Beginner</option>
                        <option>Novice</option>
                        <option>Expert</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ModuleHasCompetence.Difficulty" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button id="mAddCompetence" name="mAddCompetence" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Voeg Competentie Toe</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#mAddCompetence').click(function () {
                $('#competenceListAdd').append('</br></br>'); +
                $('#competenceListAdd').append($('#competenceFormCloneMe').clone());
            });
        </script>
    </fieldset>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/68Lc4xne/)
But how can i handle the post data? ,if I dont know the number of input fields because they are dynamicly added.

Comment: see this http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/K18L190813-How-to-get-textboxes-values-in-MVC4-created-by-jQuery.html

Comment: @Zaki It doesnt say anything for the validation, for example i post my code, it is not valid, i have to recreate the dynamic inputs with validation values.

Comment: then instead use html helpers to create them.. see here for tutorial http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html